# How to install m2eclipse to Talend Studio for big data

Tags: eclipse, plugins, talend, m2eclipse

I am using Talend Studio for big data v7.3.1. I also want to create a Java maven projects beside Talend project (because I dont want to using Eclipse and Talend studio at the same time). Talend lets me creates a maven project but it has a lot of error in pom file and I can't run any maven goals. My guess is because it lacks of m2eclipse plugin.

My question is How to install m2eclipse plugin to talend studio.

I tried to goto menu : help\Install External software and use url: https://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.5/
But i get back error:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)
  Missing requirement: m2e logback configuration 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 1.5.2.20150413-2215) requires 'osgi.bundle; ch.qos.logback.slf4j 0.9.24' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.2.20150413-2215 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.2.20150413-2215)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration [1.5.2.20150413-2215,1.5.2.20150413-2215]
```

Comment: That is a pretty old release. m2e is normally in the main release site for the Eclipse release (for example `https://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-06` for the current Eclipse release). That slf4j component is optional, you don't have to install it.

Comment: This is Talend studio developed base on Eclipse. After using latest URL and remove slf4j option. Error is: one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e PDE - Maven Integration for Eclipse Plugin Development 1.17.4.20210607-0757 (org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.feature.group 1.17.4.20210607-0757)
  Missing requirement: m2e PDE - Maven Integration for Eclipse Plugin Development 1.17.4.20210607-0757 (org.eclipse.m2e.pde.feature.feature.group 1.17.4.20210607-0757) requires 'org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.core.runtime 3.19.0' but it could not be found

Comment: You need to work out which release of Eclipse this code is based on and use the URL for that release